# Jquery Conflicts - where to start looking for the errors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am fairly new to Jquery. Now and then when i use Jquery plugins for different components of a website. Sometimes when i use more than one or two Jquery plugins on different components of the website aided by the Jquery, another component stops working.

Where to start looking for the problems? How can i start debugging? what to look for in the beginning and what to continue to look for. Any suggestions about how to start debugging would be great.

Thanks

Comment: look for `jquery no conflict`

Comment: use firefox and firebug to it https://getfirebug.com/enable

Answer (score 0):

Almost all browsers provide there debugging facility to debug javascript so when you run your website in a browser you can open development tools in your website, i uses chrome for debugging the javascript file so i opens development tools by pressing F12. Then i can open javascript file for the page and set breakpoint there only to debug the code which i want to. If you have and errors i script then those errors are also shown in the console window of the development tools. Use this link for more information
https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/

Answer (score 0):

**Major things to do**

1. Refine your jquery libraries
2. Check whether you can limit the unnecessary files
3. Do not add the js files without need

Also check for jquery conflict, Read [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) for more help.
To find the error with your plugin,

- First check your browser console for errors
- Debug the javascript file associated with the plugin.

Hope this helps !!

Answer (score 0):

use the built in web console of the browser (f12 - chrome and IE, ctrl+shift+k - ff or use firebug/firebug lite)

trace the bug also, don't use min on dev environment for debugging purposes

Answer (score 0):

**FireFox user**

Add firebug plugin to it

1. start with console to see if error is their not.

tutorial might be helpful to you

http://www.w3resource.com/web-development-tools/firebug-tutorials.php

http://www-scf.usc.edu/~csci571/Special/Tutorials/firebug-571.pdf

**Google chrome user**

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/part1/